# nuxt.js - How to cache axios call at server side for all clients

Tags: vue.js, caching, axios, nuxt.js

I am using a vue + nuxt.js application, I like to know if it is possible to cache an axios webservice call for all clients. I have to get some currency reference data and this makes not much sense that every client has to call this data.

Can someone provide me some hints or even an example? Thx.

Answer (score 8):

Here is working solution with latest Nuxt 2.11, using locally defined module.

First add a local module to nuxt.config.js

```
modules: [
   "@/modules/axCache",
...
]
```

Then

```
//  modules/axCache.js
import LRU from "lru-cache"

export default function(_moduleOptions) {
  const ONE_HOUR = 1000 * 60 * 60
  const axCache = new LRU({ maxAge: ONE_HOUR })

  this.nuxt.hook("vue-renderer:ssr:prepareContext", ssrContext => {
    ssrContext.$axCache = axCache
  })
}
```

and

```
// plugins/axios.js
import { cacheAdapterEnhancer } from "axios-extensions"
import LRU from "lru-cache"
const ONE_HOUR = 1000 * 60 * 60

export default function({ $axios, ssrContext }) {
  const defaultCache = process.server
    ? ssrContext.$axCache
    : new LRU({ maxAge: ONE_HOUR })

  const defaults = $axios.defaults
  // https://github.com/kuitos/axios-extensions
  defaults.adapter = cacheAdapterEnhancer(defaults.adapter, {
    enabledByDefault: false,
    cacheFlag: "useCache",
    defaultCache
  })
}
```

Note, this works for both server/client sides and can be configured to work only on one side.

solution found on: https://github.com/nuxt-community/axios-module/issues/99

Comment: thank you, can this cache be shared across the clients if it is used in servermode, or  will still a cache per client created?

Comment: Actually, found out this and I am currently using this. Also I am using axios with vuex in order to keep requests at minimum. https://gist.github.com/Tuarisa/b7c07289eb32b2a7a77be270e1c8360f

You add a plugin and install the required dependencies, i don’t know what you mean by multiple clients sharing the same cache? Can you explain?

Answer (score 2):

here is the new solution for cache the whole page

even you can cache consistent api like menu if you need

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nuxt-perfect-cache

`npm i nuxt-perfect-cache`

```
// nuxt.config.js

modules: [
    [
        'nuxt-perfect-cache',
        {
          disable: false,
          appendHost: true,
          ignoreConnectionErrors:false, //it's better to be true in production
          prefix: 'r-',
          url: 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379',
          getCacheData(route, context) {          
            if (route !== '/') {
              return false
            }
            return { key: 'my-home-page', expire: 60 * 60 }//1hour
          }
        }
      ]
]
```

then for cache your api response in redis for all clients:

```
asyncData(ctx) {
    return ctx.$cacheFetch({ key: 'myApiKey', expire: 60 * 2 }, () => {
      console.log('my callback called*******')
      return ctx.$axios.$get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    })
  }
```